# How to fix CWE 73 External Control of File Name or Path

Tags: java, eclipse, security, path, veracode

During veracode scan i got CWE 73 issue in my result. Can someone suggest me how to fix this solution for the below coding scenario?

The existing solutions provide is not working,also i would like to know any ESAPI properties can be used to get rid of this issue?

try
    {
          String serviceFile = System.getProperty("PROP", "");
          logger.info("service A", "Loading service file [" + serviceFile+ "].");**//Security Issue CWE 73 Occurs in this line**
    }

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for it:

1. Validate with a whitelist but use the input from the entry point As
   we mentioned at Use a list of hardcoded values.
2. Validate with a simple regular expression whitelist
3. Canonicalise the input and validate the path

I used the first and second solutions and work fine.

More info at: https://community.veracode.com/s/article/how-do-i-fix-cwe-73-external-control-of-file-name-or-path-in-java

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://community.veracode.com/s/article/how-do-i-fix-cwe-73-external-control-of-file-name-or-path-in-java) document provides detailed information on recommended remedies any explicit custom solution. In my case, I tried whitelisting or blacklisting patterns in the provided method parameters however that still did not resolve CWE-73 risk.  I think thats expected and the document does state this:

> A static engine is limited in what it can detect. It can only scan your code, it won’t actually run your code (unlike Dynamic Scanning). So it won’t pick up any custom validation (if conditions, regular expressions, etc.). But that doesn’t mean that this is not a perfectly valid solution that removes the risk!

I tried my custom blacklisted pattern based solution and annotated the method with FilePathCleanser as documented in [here](https://docs.veracode.com/r/t_annotate_java) and it resolved CWE-73 and veracode no longer shows that as a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate this PROP string with Recommended OWASP ESAPI Validator methods, like below.

Example:

```
String PropParam= ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("",System.getProperty("PROP", ""),"FileRegex",false);
```

`FileRegex` is the Regular Expression against which PROP string i.e. path of the file is getting validated.

Define `FileRegex = ^(.+)\/([^\/]+)$` in Validator.properties.